# Cabal build-depends and transitive dependencies

Tags: cabal

Where can I find information about semantics of `build-depends` field in .cabal file?

My interpretation is that it is misleading and quite bad for the user experience:

- cabal will figure out what are dependencies for a package to install when asked
- cabal will find a plan along with matching versions
- cabal will require you to manually enter all transitive dependencies in a .cabal file (with version ranges) to build a project

If a library has a "convenience" wrapper, does my cabal file have to look like this?

```
build-depends:     base >= 4.7 && < 5
                 , diagrams >= 1.0
                 , diagrams-core >= 1.0
                 , diagrams-lib >= 1.0
                 , diagrams-contrib >= 1.0
                 , diagrams-svg >= 1.0
```